# Socket/bind/listen in Centos7 not working but does in Centos6

Tags: linux, sockets, centos6, centos7, listen

I am attempting to run a program that seems to be having Centos 7 "block" or stop it from listening on a socket/port.

The code uses socket/sockoptions/bind/listen. At various points I've added checks to output that it is actually listening.

Here is a code snippet I use to verify it's listening.

```
    int val;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(val);
    if (getsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ACCEPTCONN, &val, &len) == -1)
      sprintf(buf,"fd %d is not a socket\n", s);
    else if (val)
      sprintf(buf,"fd %d is a listening socket(%d)\n", s,val);
    else
      sprintf(buf,"fd %d is a non-listening socket(%d)\n", s,val);
    Log(buf);
```

Log output was

```
Fri Aug  5 16:06:40 2016 :: _loop:fd 0 is a listening socket(1)
```

I've disabled selinux, firewalld (installed iptables-services and opened tcp on port 7777). When I launch the program I use "nmap -sT -O localhost" and "netstat -anp | grep 7777". Neither of which show port 7777 listening. Telneting to the port (localhost or the ip) are refused. I've tried running the application as root and a user.

Now, I take the exact same code and compile/run on Centos 6 it works w/o a hitch.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what in Centos7 is interfering with it? I've been searching all the socket documentation and can't see anything that suggests there is a difference between them so I'm guessing there is some OS feature I am just not seeing that would cause this.

Addtional:

7777 is the port the application is set to use.

The version of iptables I am using:

```
# rpm -aq |grep iptables
iptables-services-1.4.21-16.el7.x86_64
iptables-1.4.21-16.el7.x86_64`
```

I've also completely disabled firewalld and iptables.

```
systemctl list-unit-files |grep firewall
firewalld.service                           disabled

systemctl list-unit-files |grep iptable
iptables.service                            disabled
```

Comment: How's the 7777 get in there? You should probably show that context in your code. Also whats "iptables-services" you've installed? Probably you have some blocking rules. Check `sudo iptables-save`

Comment: I've updated the notes to include information that might answer your questions. I had disabled iptables/firewalld (to be certain) and port 7777 is the port I use in the application to listen on.

Comment: Try `nc -l -p 7777 & netstat -natulp  | grep 7777` on both see what happens. Dont know what `iptables.service` is on CentOS but does it necessarily mean you have no rules?

Comment: With iptables.services and firewalld.services disabled, correct it currently has no rules. 

I ran the command and here is what I saw `]# nc -l -p 7777 & netstat -natulp | grep 7777
[1] 4999
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7777            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4999/nc
tcp6       0      0 :::7777                 :::*                    LISTEN      4999/nc
`

Comment: You can list the counters on each rule in iptables to see what is blocking. Yo can capture traffic with wireshark to see where it stops.